# Django Database issues after deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am having this issue below since deploying to Heroku. Depending on the page, the model causing the error changes, but the issue is still the same across.

The example I will provide, gets triggered from the trailer-locations/ page.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://nameless-ravine-45956.herokuapp.com/trailer-locations/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.10.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'apps.home',
 'apps.config']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (column home_trailerlocation.statusCode does not exist
LINE 1: ...State", "home_trailerlocation"."locationCountry", "home_trai...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/apps/home/views.py", line 103, in trailerLocations
    timestamp = trailers[0]['trailerlocation__updated_at']
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 317, in __getitem__
    qs._fetch_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 109, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1130, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /trailer-locations/
Exception Value: column home_trailerlocation.statusCode does not exist
LINE 1: ...State", "home_trailerlocation"."locationCountry", "home_trai...
```

Before I share my TrailerLocation Model, I also need to discuss my Trailer Model. When creating an entry into my Trailer Model, I have 2 functions that also create entries into the TrailerLocation and TrailerTrip Model, I will outline all of these below.

Trailer Model

```
class Trailer(models.Model):
    trailerNumber = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    trailerPlateState = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    trailerPlateNumber = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    trailerLeaseCompany = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.trailerNumber

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if TrailerLocation.objects.filter(trailer__trailerNumber=self.trailerNumber).exists() is False:
            createFirstTrailerLoc(self.id)
        if TrailerTrip.objects.filter(trailer__trailerNumber=self.trailerNumber).exists() is False:
            createFirstTrailerTrip(self.id)
```

The 2 Helper Functions createFirstTrailerLoc() and createFirstTrailerTrip() For reference, these are contained within models.py

```
def createFirstTrailerLoc(trailerId):
    trailer = Trailer.objects.get(id=trailerId)
    trailerLocation = TrailerLocation(trailer=trailer)
    trailerLocation.save()


def createFirstTrailerTrip(trailerId):
    trailer = Trailer.objects.get(id=trailerId)
    trailerTrip = TrailerTrip(trailer=trailer)
    trailerTrip.save()
```

TrailerLocation Model

```
    trailer = models.OneToOneField(Trailer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    locationCity = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    locationState = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    locationCountry = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    statusCode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.trailer.trailerNumber
```

TrailerTrip Model

```
class TrailerTrip(models.Model):
    trailer = models.OneToOneField(Trailer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shipment = models.OneToOneField(Shipment, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    dateYardEmpty = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    dateDrayPickedUp = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    dateDrayReturnedLoaded = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    dateCarrierPickedUpLoaded = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    dateCarrierDelivered = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    dateCarrierReturnedEmpty = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.trailer.trailerNumber

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.dateCarrierReturnedEmpty is not None:
            createTripReport(self.id, self.shipment.id, self.trailer.id)
            resetTrailerTrip(self.id)
        if self.dateCarrierDelivered is not None:
            shipment = Shipment.objects.get(id=self.shipment.id)
            shipment.loadDelivered = True
            shipment.save()
```

That covers all possible Models that could be involved in the error I am experiencing. Now I will show the View for trailer-locations/

trailerLocations View

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def trailerLocations(request):
    trailers = trailerLocQuery()
    timestamp = trailers[0]['trailerlocation__updated_at']

    context = {'trailers': trailers, 'timestamp': timestamp}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'refresh' in request.POST:
            updateTrailerLocations()
            return redirect('trailerLocations')
        if 'email' in request.POST:
            sendLocEmail()
            return redirect('trailerLocations')
        if 'csv' in request.POST:
            createCsv()
            return redirect('trailerLocations')
    return render(request, "home/trailer-location-list.html", context)
```

trailerLocQuery() mentioned in the view above

```
def trailerLocQuery():
    trailers = Trailer.objects.all().values(
        'trailerNumber',
        'id',
        'trailerlocation__locationCity',
        'trailerlocation__locationState',
        'trailerlocation__locationCountry',
        'trailerlocation__statusCode',
        'trailertrip__shipment__loadNumber',
        'trailertrip__shipment__destinationCity',
        'trailertrip__shipment__destinationState',
        'trailerlocation__updated_at',
        'trailertrip__shipment__carrier',
        'shipment__id'
    )
        # .order_by('-trailerlocation__statusCode')
    return trailers
```

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and migrate command ?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Yes I did

Comment: @NicholasTallarico, are you entirely sure your migrations are correct? This does look like an issue where the migrations aren't all applied.

Comment: @Chris What do you mean by correct?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that... I literally mean "are they correct?" Are they up to date with all of your model changes? Do they run without error? If you run them on a brand new database, do you end up with the right database structure? If your migrations build a database that doesn't match your models they are incorrect and will result in errors like this.

Comment: @Chris Well because of the error, I have never been able to test them during live deployment. But locally, they work fine.

Comment: "But locally, they work fine"—Have you tried using them on a brand new database locally to see if you get working code? Are you using the same database server locally and in production?